# Would unintelligent humanoids end up losing their language and inventive powers?

Tags: evolution, humanoid, intelligence

If a hominid with a human-like mind became less intelligent due to adaptation to a reduction in food, would this be likely to lead to the loss of language and the ability to make complex tools?

Comment: Better define "intelligence" -- there are a number of species that don't keep records and can't talk (in ways we can recognize) but make, use, and invent tools.  Crows and their kin, for instance, and some of the great apes.  And most humans don't...

Comment: @ARogueAnt. It seems not about possibility of deevolution, but capacities of intelligence, in that regard Zeiss made a good point, thankfully I read the reminder before wrote they will forget eveything, lol. Also to add to examples - ants have a limited ways and capacities and brains - but they use their ant algorithms to build "constructions" and farms - so yeah - seems it can be anything and no definitive answer can be provided at all. Birds do nests, all sorts, complex, spiders do nets.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Does my edit help explain what the reduction in intelligence would be? I'm not really sure about the specifics of intelligence

Comment: Natural selection selects for the *combination* of traits likely to increase the number of offspring who reach sexual maturity. What this combination is we most usually can tell after the fact; as the saying goes, in controlled conditions of environmental change, competition for resources and other stressors, natural evolution does whatever it likes. If you want your small humanoids to have lost language, they will have lost language. If you want them to preserve language and the ability to make tools to make tools, they will preserve them.

Comment: How much does the brain of a corvid or a parrot weigh? Not more than 20 grams (less than an traditionalle Englisshe ounce). Are corvids and parrots stupid? No, they are not. Imagine what a raven could do with a brain weighing half a kilogram (about a pound).

Comment: @AlexP But is the loss of language and technology plausible?

Comment: If intelligence is affected "across the board" (like measured by IQ score) then capabilities would deteriorate, but won't disappear completely. If certain regions of the brain are affected, the the entire capability (like speech) can be wiped out.

Comment: @Alexander How would intelligence be affected in the scenario in the question?

Comment: Plausibility is a function of the skill of the story teller, not a function of the elements of the plot. Is it plausible that Ulysses and his companions get stranded on a lush island inhabited by the most beautiful witch Circe, who presently enchants them (except Ulysses, for plot reasons) with her song and transforms them into pigs (who somehow keep their human minds)? Homer makes it plausible. A story can be plausible (comes from Latin "worthy to be applauded") without being realistic.

Comment: "Reduction in food" in humans would not cause significant change in intelligence. However, homo sapiens may evolve into something else - and there is no real way of telling how intelligent those species would be.

Comment: @Alexander If there is less food availible, then the individuals who need less food will survive better. This will lead to the brain, alongside the rest of the body, using less energy, which, I assume, will reduce intelligence

Comment: @Ichthys King it's very difficult to predict how this reduction will go in new species. For Homo Sapiens, if we lose our civilized status (being "raised by wolves", for example), we would lose the language - but the evolutionary capability to learn language.

Comment: Raised by wolves - good point actually, it does not take evolution to lose language or(and) tool making abilities. And reinvent it from scratch will take looong time, enough for evolution to have some time to bring changes as well thus making possible or impossible any combination, any comination does include - remove or enhance the ability to learn or create. Really, you have total freedom in that regard, for story telling it may be a good thing, not so good however for making a reasonable answer.

Comment: hominids in limited food averments got smaller not less intelligent, intelligence is very useful in a limited resource environment.

Comment: I wonder why opening, comments and answer focus on "intelligence". The question  title is about language and inventive skills. Both behavioural aspects are much easier to research than "intelligence" is. Finds of complex tools  would indicate inventive skills, brain structural changes *could* indicate the use of language, that is more difficult to pinpoint. Second remark: it may be more inappropriate to associate "homo" with language rather than *hominids*  https://bmcbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12915-017-0405-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Zeiss' answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/207692/39389) seems to be a perfectly correct answer to your question, because we just don't really know. In contrast, it is completely unsuitable for the purpose for which the question was most likely asked. Therefore, I will try to answer differently.

Starting with definition:

> [Natural selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_selection) is one mechanism of biological evolution that leads to directed changes in populations that increase their average adaptation, or adaptation to environmental conditions.
> The measure of success in natural selection is fitness. It can be considered at the level of individuals or individual genes. Organisms with advantageous traits are more likely to survive and reproduce, leading to an increased frequency of advantageous genes in the population.

Consider an environment with limited access to food. (As an aside, it is also important how limited the resources will be in this environment). With a limited amount of food, one would expect a correspondingly large reduction in population, as is often seen in [natural processes of animal population regulation](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3558271) rather than a significant reduction in energy (food) requirements.

So in such an environment, will natural selection promote individuals that need less food, or rather those that will be able to obtain significantly more food than other individuals of the species or than other species competing for the same food?

In all likelihood, human (or human-like) brain capacity is a trait that significantly helps adaptation to an environment with reduced food supply, so on a general level one might expect that natural selection is unlikely to promote individuals with much weaker intelligence, although it is possible that other traits such as speed, agility or reflex might be even more important and promoted.

There may, of course, be combinations of adverse environmental conditions that will actively promote individuals with less intellectual abilities. I can quickly think of some kind of radiation that increases the risk of brain cancer in young (adolescent) individuals with higher brain activity, or some kind of brain parasite that is more likely to attack such individuals. But these, in turn, are factors that intelligent populations, at the appropriate level of development of civilization (such as humans more or less since the nineteenth or twentieth century) would be able to cope with. So the occurrence of such factors would have to be preceded by the collapse of civilization or would be important in species that have not yet developed a technical civilization. So this kind of situation is rather unlikely and even if such combination of conditions happens, it will not be caused only by limited resources (or strictly reduced food supply). It seems to me that there is a much higher probability of the complete extinction of a humanoid species due to extremely unfavorable environmental conditions than the emergence of such conditions that will result in the survival of the species but with significantly reduced intellectual abilities.

To summarize my answer. I consider extremely unlikely the occurrence of such environmental changes that would cause a significant reduction in humanoid intelligence, one that would lead to the disappearance of language or tool-making skills, although of course it is not impossible.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer here is, we don't really know.

There is speculation that this is more or less what happened to *Homo Floresiensis* ("Hobbits" of Flores Island), who had significantly smaller brains than modern humans as well as being under four feet tall -- but so far, we have so little evidence beyond their mere existence, we don't even know if their smaller brains actually made them less intelligent, or if so, whether they were *enough* less intelligent to lose some of the mental abilities we normally associate with human populations.

The link between brain size and intelligence itself is a bit shaky, based on my reading; at least one of our ancestor species (Neanderthal) had slightly larger brains, on average, than we do, yet they're gone and only their genes remain, bred into our own lines.

Yes, a big brain needs lots of energy to operate, as well as having very important nutritional requirements for development (adequate fat and protein in the diet, for instance).  What happens over evolutionary time if those needs aren't met, we don't know.  Does a population get smaller and less smart, or do they just die out?

If you pay attention to anthropology research, you'll know as soon as I do.